Proving that $b+\frac{1}{a(b-a)}\ge 3$ , if $b>a>0$
Prove that $b+\frac{1}{a(b-a)}\ge 3$ , if $b>a>0$
My Attempt :
We can see that $b+\frac{1}{a(b-a)}\ge 3$ if $b>a>0$
By using AM-GM inequality of 3 variables as
$$\frac{a+(b-a)+\frac{1}{a(b-a)}}{3}\ge \left(a(b-a)\frac{1}{a(b-a)}\right)^{1/3},$$
where equality holds when $a=1,b=2$.
Question: How else it can be proved?

Let us keep $b$ fixed & vary $a$ to get the minimum.
The target will be minimized when the fraction is minimized.
That is minimized when the Denominator is maximized.
That maximization is at $a=b-a$ , hence $b=2a$
Plug that into the given target.
We will get :
$2a+1/a^2$
This is minimized when :
$2-2/a^3=0$
Hence $a=1$
Hence $b=2$
Minimum value [ at $(a,b)=(1,2)$ ] is $2+1/(1(2-1))=3$

From the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$b(a-b) \leqslant \left(\frac{b+a-b}{2}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{4}.$$
Therefore
$$a+\frac{1}{b(a-b)} \geqslant a+\frac{4}{a^2}=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{4}{a^2} \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{a^2}}=3.$$
Done.
